# This type of file could harm your computer

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I am developing a PHP web application in Apache server and it seems to work well with all major browsers even IE8. The only problem is with IE9. Basically my application lets users download a 30 day trial which is an exe file. At the download prompt, the dialog says "This type of file could harm your computer".

Some websites like red-gate.com and microsoft.com allows downloading of exe files but without this warning in IE9. What am I missing here?? I have some possible causes for this problem:

1. Is this specific only to Apache hosted websites? Its because red-gate and microsoft.com are hosted in IIS/ASP.NET platform.
2. The exe file is not digitally signed?
3. Or this is simply a bug in IE9?

I would like the message "This type of file could harm your computer" to be completely remove when users are downloading the exe files using IE9. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content-disposition header is the key.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2566263